# How to start text in next line after subsubsubtitle in rmarkdown when generating pdf?

Tags: r, latex, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I have some .Rmd files in which I need to make some changes to the layout in subsections. This example shows what I need to do.

This is an example Rmd code:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  html_document: default
mainfont: Calibri Light
header-includes:
- \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{test}
- \usepackage{floatrow}
- \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{here}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
---

# Article

## title

#### subsubsubtitle {-}

Here is some text
```

The result if generating pdf is:

[image]

But what I really want is:
[image]

So I want the text to be starting on the next line instead of right after the section header. (Also I don't want the subsection to be numbered and, that's why I put the `{-}` right after it.)

Does someone know how to manage this?

Comment: this looks relevant: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addresses the Latex side of the problem.

The `\paragraph`, which is what `\subsubsubsection` is, just has different formatting and presentation.  One of the things is that it doesn't start a new line.  This is in pure Latex.

Ways around it:

- The package `titlesec` allows you to customize the title appearance a lot. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection).
- Do it in Latex itself -- [re]define how `\paragraph` works -- see the [above post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection), and/or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164636/subsubsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-count-not-reset-when-starting-a).
- Tweak it in the next itself, adding a newline. See below.

There may be a more direct way in `.Rmd` but I am not familiar with it and this has the Latex tag.

---

I have to address another aspect of this, without debating poster's purpose.  Such deep hierarchy may indicate a need to rethink the structure. Does it help in making the document easier and more intuitive to use, or does it do the opposite?

With that out of the way, here are some direct ways of making it add a line, as requested.

Tweak it in the text itself, so that it takes a newline (`\newline` alone doesn't work).

```
\paragraph{title_text}
\mbox{ }\\
paragraph text here
```

Another way

```
\paragraph{title_text} \hspace{0pt} \\
paragraph text here
```

---

With [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package you can redefine the `\paragraph`, by changing `[runin]` to `[hung]`

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hung]           % default is [runin] 
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}  
     {\theparagraph}{1em}{}
```

Or, can explicitly change the spacings

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\paragraph}
        {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

For a succinct summary of the `titlesec` package see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti).

All this is straight-up Latex and I am not sure how it works with `.Rmd`.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, so I need to reformat the subsubsubsection in latex. The only thing I want to add is letting it start a new line. Do you have a more precise example?

Comment: @user1983395  Added to the post, three ways between two different approaches.  Please let me know how it works.

Comment: It worked! I used the tweak in the text itself. I think you are absolutely right regarding these kind of changes in the existing format. My purpose was to copy a layout that is not exactly the same as the predifined one. With your help I think I succeeded. thanks!

Comment: @user1983395  Great :).  I thought that there was a reason, just had to say it.  Btw, that `titlesec` is good for customizing how things look, if you need to do that in the future.  It may be a good idea to give it a shot here, as well.  It's a systemic solution, for every paragraph you have.  (If it works with .Rmd)

Comment: @user1983395  I ran into another way to add a new line -- `\paragraph{title_text} hspace{0pt} \\ `, and into a [nice page about it](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting). Just letting you know.